# How to crop a picture using a cloud pattern like SnagIt does?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a picture that I can open with Illustrator and then I want to crop it using a cloud shape like SnagIt does very easily but I'd rather don't buy it yet if I can accomplish the same using Illustrator.

How can I do that? I need the cloud pattern first ... is there a stock of reusable patterns somewhere?

Comment: Can you please show an example of what Snagit does, or what you are trying to achieve.  What kind of image are you trying to crop?  Is it a raster image, or a vector image?  Are you perhaps asking about how to make a clipping mask?  Not sure what you mean by a cloud pattern.  Do you mean single cloud shape,  or a bunch of clouds in a pattern?  There are many stock art sites that sell vectors for Adobe Illustrator - but it's not exactly hard to draw a cloud.  Please add details to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry for my poor terminology I am not a designer :( indeed I need a clipping mask to have the shape of the contour of my image as a cloud, the content of the image is a wordcloud ... I import my image in Illustrator and it converts it to editable objects/path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21015/how-to-crop-an-image-in-illustrator)

Comment: Why cant you just make your own cloud?

Comment: @SkyWalker - sorry I'm still lost. Please post an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking multiple questions at once. Also, we offer assistance with design issues you might have, we will not however search the web for (free) resources, your can do that yourself. Please read our [tour] and [how to ask](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnagIt uses predefined trim edges to get its effects, and is a raster (pixel) program - you said you're pulling your word cloud into Illustrator as editable paths - so either it's coming in vector or you're Live Tracing it to become vector.

Once you're in Illustrator in an *all-vector* scenario, it's a *bit* more complicated, ***but*** you've *far* more control - you will group your disparate text and paths together, you will draw your cloud edge shape, and then you will select both the group underneath and the cloud shape above and right-click - choose "create clipping mask" and you'll be in business!

Grouped text underneath, cloud shape on top (coloured pink for clarity) - select both
[image]

Right click
[image]

Aaaand... Bob's yer Uncle!
[image]

Hope that helps!